# How to use DHTMLX Scheduler in MVC3?

Tags: scheduler, dhtmlx

I need to use DHTMLX Scheduler in MVC3 project. Is there any way that i can use it on my MVC3 project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the next links

Scheduler MVC tutorial

- http://scheduler-net.com/docs/simple_.net_application_with_scheduler.html

Scheduler MVC video tutorial

- http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/03/16/asp-net-event-calendar-video-tutorial.aspx